# 0 multiply number in floating point

Tags: numbers, floating-point

as you know single number will save in memory by following format:
`(-1)^s * 1.f * 2^e:`
and zero will save like that: `1.0000000000000000 * 2 ^ -126`

now If I multiply it to another floating point number like 3.37 `(-1) ^ 0 * 1.10101111 * 2 ^ 128` 
it will not 0 it reality,but in computer it will be 0 ,how and why?

Comment: It isn't clear if you want to know what the math unit of your cpu does to "optimize" this multiplication or if you want to know what the C/C++ standard say about it. I will suggest you remove the c and c++ tag before being flooded with "c and c++ don't require IEEE binary floating point numbers"

Comment: There is nothing C or C++ about this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out [here (Wikipedia, sorry ...)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format), there are special values for the exponent which are treated differently. If the exponent is zero, the formula for calculating the value of the number is

```
(-1)^s * 0.f * 2^(-126)   # notice 0.f instead of 1.f for other exponents
```

So, a floating point zero has simply all bits set to zero (i.e. `f=0, s=0, e=0`). The multiplication algorithms of course have to take care of this "special" exponent and set the result to zero in this case (more specifically to +Zero or -Zero accordingly ...)

Answer (score 2):

Zero is (typically) a special case in floating point representations, and in IEEE floating point, zero is represented as `0.0 * 2 ^ -126` (or whatever the exponent is—it really doesn't matter).

Comment: not quite true, if the exponent is different from -126 (which is stored as binary `0`), then one is added to the fraction digits and you would get 1.0*2^exp, which is different from zero ...

Comment: @MartinStettner If the exponent is different from -126, then the value is not zero.  There are only two representations of zero in IEEE format, both have all bits 0 except the sign bit (which can be 0 or 1).  The implicit 1 to the left of the mantissa isn't present for zero (otherwise it wouldn't be zero), nor for gradual underflow, nor for Inf and NaN (where the mantissa doesn't represent a number anyway).

Comment: @James Kanze: it is confusing (and should be avoided) to show zero in the representation you have chosen. It implies that zeroes have a very small exponent which they don't. Your showing an (invalid for sp but not for dp) exponent should go hand in hand with the implicit bit set to 1 which it always is with a valid exponent. Zero is a special case with a special definition: use that instead.

Comment: @OlofForshell I said that zero is a special case, although I recognize your point; I should have simply talked about the value of the mantissa, exponent and sign fields.  As you say, in the case of zero, the exponent and mantissa fields have the bit pattern of all 0's, and that's all there is to it.  (I guess, theoretically, 0 could be considered a normal extension of the gradual underflow representation, but I don't think that point of view helps clarity.  The first part of my answer, up to the comma, says it all.)

Comment: @James Kanze That's exactly what I wanted to say. The sentence "it really doesn't matter" in your answer could be misinterpreted so that every exponent is possible whereas it has to be `-126`.

Comment: @MartinStettner: as I attempted to convey to James Kantze: even mentioning an exponent - let alone -126 - in the floating point zero context is confusing and misleading. You will not, in any quality litterature on the subject at least, see anyone mentioning an exponent of -126. They will say that the exponent field contains 0. Besides, the exponent field is not a signed byte: it is an unsigned byte with a 126 bias. So the "-126" you guys mention is also factually incorrect because it would correspond to a byte value of 0xfe and not one of all zeroes. Get your acts together guys!

Comment: @Olof Forshell The fact is, that an exponent byte of 0x00 will be interpreted as an exponent value of -126. There are different ways to encode negative numbers in binary, so if you define a bias of 126, 0x00 *is* -126. A 0x00 value in the exponent field means an exponent *value* of -126. Additionally, if the field is 0x00, the fractional part is interpreted differently (i.e. without adding 1 to it.) But I agree that my comment might have been confusing and that mentioning -126 perhaps wasn't clever (also since it only is true for singles, whereas the 0x00 applies to all IEEE754 numbers)

Comment: On to more constructive things!

Comment: @MartinStettner The fact is that an exponent byte of 0x00 will not be interpreted as an exponent value of -126.  An exponent byte of 0x00 is a special value, which signals gradual underflow or 0.

Comment: @James Kanze I need to apologize :) You're right, exponent byte 0x01 will be signify a "normalized" value with exponent -126. 0x00 means a subnormal (underflow) number (also with exponent -126, but fewer fraction digits). Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I'll say that the math unit of the cpu has some optimization for the "special" floating point numbers, like `NaN`, `Infinity` and `0` (and note that technically in IEEE binary fp there are two `0`, a positive and a negative one) and know what to do in the three cases.

If you are interested, here http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html there is one table that shows what happens when you sum/multiply the "special" numbers between themselves.

Answer (score 0):

why: floating-point numbers set isn't continuous like R set in Math. Therefore some nubers can't be visualized correctly and rounded to the neares possible visualizable number

how: it's being rounded :)

Comment: While it's true that some numbers cannot be represented accurately with floating points, this is *not* true for numbers as "important" as zero, which has, of course, an exact representation.

Comment: i wasn't referring to thr zero being rounded or what, but answering to "it will not be zero in reality, ... why?"

Comment: @STT LCU: All numbers represented in an IEEE754-compatible floating-point unit are exact. A number in the real number set will map to the IEEE number in one of two ways: either exactly or to nearest. The situation you address is when no exact counterpart exists.

Comment: @STTLCU That part of the original question was wrong since it *will* be zero in reality.

Answer (score -2):

Rounding errors. Computers are finite